# Not taking selected item value into text..instead taking default value of spinner in android?

Tags: android, json, spinner

i am working with AlertDialog box where user gives instruction about the product through alertDialog box.In dialog box there are 2 spinner, buttons etc.when i select spinners options it should take selected value and toast it..but its taking default value. i need to save this value on server ...so it should be accurate,its saving default value to the server..i dont know where its wrong?As a newbie i am confused here...kindly help.
here is my SubMenu Activity:

```
     public class SubMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "id";
    static String COUNTRY = "name";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String status="";
    static String FLAG = "image";
    Integer i = 1;
    private static String url_create_book = "http://cloud..com/broccoli/creatinfo.php";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_menu);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        String SelectedId = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        // Get the view from listview_main.xml

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        // @Override
        //  protected void onPreExecute() {
        //  super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        //   mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubMenu.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        //   mProgressDialog.setTitle("Categories of Main categories.....");
        // Set progressdialog message
        //  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        //  mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        //  mProgressDialog.show();
        // }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonarray = JsonFunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://cloud.granddubai.com/broccoli/menu_typeitem.php?id=" + getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                //                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("main_menu_items");


                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    // map.put("id", jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));

                    map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(SubMenu.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            // Close the progressdialog
            // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long rowId) {


            final AlertDialog customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubMenu.this).create();





            customDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));









            final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup
                    , null);
            customDialog.setView(dialogView);

            final  Spinner crust, adds;
            // set the custom customDialogimation components - text, image and button



            ImageLoader imageLoader= new ImageLoader(dialogView.getContext());
            final ImageView desimage = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.desimage);

            // final  CircleImageView desimage =(CircleImageView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.desimage);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(arraylist.get(position).get("image"), desimage);

            final TextView heading = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.h1);

            final EditText spins = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinst);


            final String specialInstr=spins.getText().toString();

            heading.setText(arraylist.get(position).get("name"));

            final String hed=heading.getText().toString();

            final Button dcr=(Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.decr);

            final Button incre=(Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.incr);
            final  String crusttext, addstext;

           /* crust = (Spinner)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.crst);

            ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(SubMenu.this, R.array.Crust_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            crust.setAdapter(adapter);
            crust.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            crusttext = crust.getSelectedItem().toString();

            adds = (Spinner)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.crst);

            ArrayAdapter adapteradds = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(SubMenu.this, R.array.AddsOn_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapteradds.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            adds.setAdapter(adapteradds);
            adds.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            addstext = adds.getSelectedItem().toString();*/

            final Button cncl = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.canc);
            cncl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    customDialog.dismiss();


                }
            });
            final ImageButton crssbtn = (ImageButton) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
            crssbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    customDialog.dismiss();


                }
            });



            Button _decrease = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.incr);
            Button _increase = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.decr);

            final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.crst);
            Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.adson);

            ArrayList<String> alspinner1 = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> alspinner2 = new ArrayList<>();


            final String[] _spvalue1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Crust_array);
            final String[] _spvalue2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.AddsOn_array);
           for (int i = 0; i < _spvalue1.length; i++) {
                alspinner1.add(_spvalue1[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < _spvalue2.length; i++) {
                alspinner2.add(_spvalue2[i]);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(dialogView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, alspinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(dialogView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, alspinner2);

            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


            spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
            spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener((new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int arg2, long arg3) {
                    Object item = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                    if (item!=null) {


                        Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, item.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, "Selected",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }));









            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            addstext = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

           // Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, addstext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





            final TextView _value = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.value);
            i = Integer.parseInt(_value.getText().toString());

            final String _stringVal;
            _decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String _stringVal;
                    Log.d("src", "Decreasing value...");
                    if (i > 0) {
                        i = i - 1;
                        _stringVal = String.valueOf(i);
                        _value.setText(_stringVal);

                        Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, ""+_stringVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("src", "Value can't be less than 0");
                    }

                }
            });

            _increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String _stringVal;

                    Log.d("src", "Increasing value...");
                    i = i + 1;
                    _stringVal = String.valueOf(i);
                    _value.setText(_stringVal);
                    Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, ""+_stringVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });




            Button altok=(Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.alrtok);

            altok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //is chkIos checked?

                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubMenu.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();












                    final String spli=spins.getText().toString();
                    final   RadioGroup rgroup = (RadioGroup) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rgrp1);




                    final String rval1;
                    final  RadioButton rbtn;

                    final int selectedId = rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();



                    rbtn = (RadioButton) dialogView.findViewById(selectedId);
                    rval1 = rbtn.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, rval1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, spli, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_create_book,
                            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    if (response.trim().equals("success")) {
                                        // Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this,"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(SubMenu.this, AddToCart.class));
//your intent code here
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this,"Please Give Full Information!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                }
                            },

                            new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            })
                    {

                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("dish_name", hed);
                            params.put("type",rval1);
                         //   params.put("addson",sp);
                           // params.put("crust",crusttext);
                            params.put("special_instruction",specialInstr);

                            /*params.put("Last_Name",lname);
                            params.put("email", email);
                            params.put("Gender", rval);
                            params.put("password", passwrd);
                            params.put("confirmPasw",cpasswrd);
                            params.put("DOB",dobr);
                            params.put("sms_subscrb",status);
                            params.put("Mobile_No",mobile);*/
                            return params;
                        }
                    };

                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SubMenu.this);
                    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                }
            });















            //  crust.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            // public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {


           /* final Button ok = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ok);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    customDialog.dismiss();


                }
            });*/










            customDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                   View view, int pos, long id) {


          //  Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this,"The planet is " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }





    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

here above the string addstext and crusttext are taking default value..which is the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Demo extends Activity{
 private Spinner sp1;

onCreate()
{
 sp1=findviewbyid(id);



spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object item = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        if (item!=null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          SaveInDatabase(item.toString());
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});


    private void SaveInDatabase(String value)
   {
   //Logic to save in database;
    }
 }
```

Comment: so shud i make another java class for tht ?actually everything is in alertdialog box so ....shud it be in a same class

Comment: if i try putting saveindatatabse outside the class its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this one , in your onItemSelected Listener

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Object item = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            if (item!=null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: ok let me try..but i need to get the text from spinner and saved in database

Comment: but how to save this string into database because if i make a string and do like this.....spinn.getSelectedItem().toString();...here the spinn i have declare within a class ..but i want to add this spinn outside the class so that i can send it to database

Comment: i have got item selected but it shud save in a string which can be saved in databse

Comment: Create a method in class saveInDatabase(String value) after selecting value from spinner call the method saveInDatabase(.spinn.getSelectedItem().toString())
In method put your logic to save string in database

Comment: can u tell me through coding ..i m getiing u

Comment: i have put ur code in my question..now i want to add into srting which i can access outside d class also

Comment: see my next answer